# Slashes with Apache URL Rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

.htaccess file with mod-rewrite rules exists at the .htaccess in the public_html folder

User goes to the URL http://www.thedomain.com/download/myfile

Mod-Rewrite rules should actually tell the server to access the URL: http://www.thedomain.com/download.php?index=myfile

How can I do this on an apache server without creating another directory named "download"?
I am getting problems with the normal procedure because of the slash.

Comment: _“I am getting problems with the normal procedure because of the slash”_ – you have neither shown us what you consider the “normal procedure”, nor described what the problem actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have multiviews turned off, mod_rewrite is loaded, and then add these rules to the htaccess file in your **document root**:

```
Options -Multiviews 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^download/(.*)$ /download.php?index=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You can also add that in your vhost config but with a leading slash right after `^`:

```
Options -Multiviews 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/download/(.*)$ /download.php?index=$1 [L,QSA]
```